# form not calling appropriate function in django

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a form in my django app and it calls a method called create in the view. The form is present in the **index.html template**. The form code is:

index.html

```
    {% if list %}
    <ul>
    {% for obj in list %}
        <li><a href="/attributes/{{ obj.attr1}}/">{{ obj.attr1 }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p><h3>Create</h3></p>
    <form action="{% url 'create' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <li>Attr1: <input type="text" name="attr1" id="attr1" value="{{attr1}}" /></li><br />
        <li>Attr2: <input type="text" name="attr2" id="attr2" value="{{attr2}}" /></li><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </form>
{% endif %}
```

The create function in the view is:

```
def create(request):
    print 'Create URL Matched'
    attr1 = request.POST['issuer']
    attr2 = request.POST['attr2']
    obj = IDPAttributes(a=attr1, b=attr2)
    obj.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

EDIT: Updated attributes/urls.py

```
 urlpatterns = patterns('', url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<attr1>\w+)/$', views.listattr, name='listattr'),
    url(r'^edit/(?P<attr1>\w+)/$', views.edit, name='edit'),
    url(r'^edit/(?P<attr1>\w+)/update/$', views.update, name='update'),
    url(r'^create/$', views.create, name='create'),
    url(r'^delete/$', views.delete, name='delete'))
```

When I submit the form to be deleted, it does not enter the create method. I checked the URL of the post method and its pointing to http://127.0.0.1:8000/attributes/create/.

What may be the issue for this to happen? Is there some issue in URL mapping?

EDIT: create URL was given as delete URL in the question by mistake

Comment: You have create() method in views, but no mention of it in urls.py.
The form `action` attribute is pointing where the POST request will go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^(?P<attr1>\w+)/$` regex  catches all urls with `/attributes/` prefix so it should be the last url in the `urlpatterns`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^edit/(?P<attr1>\w+)/$', views.edit, name='edit'),
    url(r'^edit/(?P<attr1>\w+)/update/$', views.update, name='update'),
    url(r'^create/$', views.create, name='create'),
    url(r'^delete/$', views.delete, name='delete'),
    url(r'^(?P<attr1>\w+)/$', views.listattr, name='listattr'),
```

Comment: i have added it. still its not going there

Comment: Correct the `<form>` tag as I suggest in the answer.

Comment: is it because of it being in index.html and that its not able to map the URL.

Comment: `{% url %}` tag works in all templates. What happens then you click on "Create" button?

Comment: it goes into the main index view function and then gets redirected to another method(list), when this create method should be called.

Comment: Ok, show the **whole** code of your main `urls.py` (where you include `attributes.urls`).

Comment: urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'attributes/', include('attributes.urls')),
)

Comment: Can update the question and show the whole `attributes/urls.py`?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are missing `^` from your create url. It should be

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^create/$', views.create, name='create'))
```

Comment: added that as well. still am getting redirected to some other function

Comment: check if other urls in urls.py are missing `^`. If its missing, then add `^` to it like `url(r'^`

Comment: have checked the rest of the URL's. able to map the other URL's but not this one

Comment: Then check if you have mistakenly imported wrong views.create

Comment: what happens is that listattr method gets called from the index view, and there i get an error because of a missing attribute.